# Woocommerce set_price is not working inside woocommerce_before_calculate_totals hook [ custom plugin ]

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I tried to add my custom wholesale price to products. So I created custom shop page with manual coding. 
When I tried to set the wholesale price (custom price) it always applies the original price.

I put a log inside the  `woocommerce_before_calculate_totals` hook it's working but price is not getting applied instead it's comes with original price of the product.

**Add to cart API:**

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'my_plugin/v1/', '/cart/add', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::EDITABLE,
        'args'=>["operation"],
        'callback' => 'my_plugin_cart_operations',
    ));
    register_rest_route( 'my_plugin/v1/', '/cart/get', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_Server::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'my_plugin_get_cart',
    ));
});

function euca_cart_operations(){
    defined( 'WC_ABSPATH' ) || exit;

    include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/wc-cart-functions.php';
    include_once WC_ABSPATH . 'includes/class-wc-cart.php';

    if ( is_null( WC()->cart ) ) {
        wc_load_cart();
    }
    $data=$_REQUEST;
    $product_id=$data['product_id']; //here product is variation id because it's coming from wholesale page
    $quantity=$data['quantity'];
    $variation_id=$data['variation_id'];
    return WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id,$quantity,$variation_id )
}
```

**Hook**

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'my_plugin_test', 20,1);

function my_plugin_test($cart){
    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $item ) {
        $wholesale=get_post_meta( $value['data']->variation_id, 'wholesale_customer_wholesale_price', true ); //I'm getting this too
        $txt = "Mine Product-->".$item ['data']->id ."---> Price :".$wholesale;
        file_put_contents('logs.txt', $txt.PHP_EOL , FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX)
        $item['data']->set_price( 40 ); //custom price
    }
}
```

Comment: Some other mistakes in your code like: `$value['data']->variation_id` that should be replaced by `$item['data']->get_variation_id()` and also `$item ['data']->id` that should be replaced by `$item['data']->get_id()`…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I even tried to give static price. Tha's also not working.

Comment: In my comment I am just pointing some errors in your code, but as you can see, I am not answering the question…